# turing computable function

Tags: theory, turing-machines

Here are few True False questions: Somebody please answer these:

1. Let F(0) = 1, and let F(n) = 2^F(n-1) for n>0. 
   Then Is F Turing-Computable?
2. No language which has an ambiguous context-free grammar can be accepted by a DPDA. Is this true ? If not which grammar is that.

Comment: is this a Physics question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), ask yourself this question: could you write a computer program that could compute this function?  If so, then by the Church-Turing thesis, then you know that there must be a TM that could do the same computation, so the function is computable.  If not, then you know that no TM could evaluate the function either.

For (2), remember that ambiguity is a property of *grammars*.  There can be multiple grammars for the same language.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the first one is true.

According to the Church–Turing thesis, computable functions are exactly the functions that can be calculated using a mechanical calculation device given unlimited amounts of time and storage space. Equivalently, this thesis states that any function which has an algorithm is computable.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. However If that is the case, Every function that can be mathematically defined is Turing computable?

Comment: Apparently according to numerous reviewers unless a computation is [Pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) it may not be a computable function.